# Variable data into different size artboard, How to do it in Adobe Illustrator CS6

Tags: dataset, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I'm making the Facebook Ad of 3 different sizes using Artboard Tool initiating the XML data-set, it works fine, **as far as I'm duplicating the same artboard it does not show changes in the duplicated artboard.** the Ad contains 3 different sizes and similar style

I'm using Adobe Illustrator CS6 at this moment, I'm unable to find an option or a trick that can do the magic. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you need to assign all the variables anew ('Make Text Dynamic') every time you make a copy of existing objects linked with variables.

- Select the text objects 'WordPress hosting' and 'Ad Messenger'
- Click on the variable 'Text1'
- Click on icon 'Make Text Dynamic'

Here we go. Now you can change the Data Sets and get your actual texts in variables from these sets.

And I think the question likely belongs Graphic Design department: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com